# Showing Attribute Tables in GeoExt

Tags: database, geoext, table

We are making a simple webmap with a Postgis database and Geoserver. So now we have the layers working in Geoserver and we can see the cartography and the the features using GeoExt, but we're not able to see the database related to them. Our commitment is to have a frame at botton of the page, or a popup, where the attribute table could be seen once a single feature is selected o maybe the entire layer if we select it.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Here you find a workshop which shows you how to do that: http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/geoext/stores/getfeatureinfo.html